# Rails render flash error message from child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got Rails 5 monolith app where inside the registration form Doctor/Admin can create a Registrant (as a Caregiver) with linked Patient (new object `CaregiverPatient` represents that).

```
  def create
    @registrant = Registrant.new(registrant_params)
    @patient = Registrant.find(session[:patient_id_to_add_caregiver]) if session[:patient_id_to_add_caregiver]
    if @registrant.save
      # other objects that must be created (...)
      CaregiverPatient.create!(patient: @patient, caregiver: @registrant, linked_by: current_login.user.id, link_description: 0) if @patient.present?
      redirect_to registrant_path(@registrant), notice: 'Registrant Added'
    else
      build_registrant_associations
      render :new, { errors: errors.full_message }
    end
  end
```

Caregiver can have only one linked Patient. How to display error message from `CaregiverPatient` validation and prevent the `@registrant` from being saved if such an error occurs?

With this code I'm getting an error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in RegistrantsController#create
> Validation failed: Caregiver cannot be assigned a caregiver

Which is because of `create!` I guess but how to handle this to display flash message inside the form?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `.create!`? For your `@registrant`, you're using `.save` instead of `.create!` to work with the result of it.

Comment: @pdu I used it because I thought it will display ActiveRecord out of the box somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the transaction: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

This allows you to handle exceptions from both `create!` and `save!` and prevent `@registrant` from being saved.

I consider your code should looks something like

```
def create
  @registrant = Registrant.new(registrant_params)
  @patient = Registrant.find(session[:patient_id_to_add_caregiver]) if session[:patient_id_to_add_caregiver]

  begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          @registrant.save!
          #other objects creation
          CaregiverPatient.create!(patient: @patient, caregiver: @registrant, linked_by: current_login.user.id, link_description: 0) if @patient.present?
          redirect_to registrant_path(@registrant), notice: 'Registrant Added'
      end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
      build_registrant_associations
      render :new, { errors: exception.message }
  end
end
```